# Convert all the .less to .css files

Tags: shell, less

how to use node or shell to make all the less convert to css?
things like this,in my folder, i have many less file, before they upload,i have to convert them to css file,is there a better way to convert all the folders which has .less file convert to the .css file

in a bad way, I use `lessc -x example.less > example.css`,but there are many files to convert,so I should change my method to this question. Can you give me some advices?

Comment: If it's OK for you, you could use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), although I know it's possible to do it via shell (sorry, I don't know the "how").

Comment: I found the "Grunt"！It fascinates me more!Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with simple bash loop (just type it in in your command line):

```
for f in *.less; do lessc -x $f ${f/.less/.css}; done
```

This will iterate over all LESS files in the current directory and invoke `lessc` on each one.

The `${f/.less/.css}` for output file name means "original name with `.less` replaced with `.css`".